# Creating daterange in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the date range:

```
'20180504' and '20180425'
```

I want to write a query that would return the following dates

```
'20180504'
'20180503'
'20180502'
'20180501'
'20180430'
'20180429'
'20180428'
'20180427'
'20180426'
'20180425'
```

Could anyone suggest what would be the best way to generate dates like these? The date format should be same as above, because I would use it to extract data from another table. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/347)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2018-04-25' + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2018-04-25' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2018-05-04'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/347/0)**:

```
|    VALUE |
|----------|
| 20180425 |
| 20180426 |
| 20180427 |
| 20180428 |
| 20180429 |
| 20180430 |
| 20180501 |
| 20180502 |
| 20180503 |
| 20180504 |
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want a string output, so you can generate the dates and then convert to strings:

```
with dates as (
      select date '2018-04-25' + level - 1 as dte
      from dual
      connect by date '2018-04-25' + level - 1 <= date '2018-05-04'
     )
select to_char(dte, 'YYYYMMDD')
from dates;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/WEJ22491).